# Unable To Install IBM I Access on Windows 7 (could not read value InstallPath from key)

Tags: db2, db2-connect, iseries-navigator

**This is the Error Message I am Getting when i try to install the IBM IAccess**

[image: Error]
I Uninstalled The IBM IAccess from my system. when I tried to reinstall it,I am getting The above Error.
Its very Important for me to get IBM IAccess Installed on windows 7. can any one please please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens when values are left behind by the uninstall (not common).  Open a cmd.exe and check as follows (choose the right line based on your PC's bitness):

64-bit:  reg query "hklm\software\wow6432node\ibm\client access\currentversion" 
32-bit:  reg query "hklm\software\ibm\client access\currentversion"

If IBM i Access for Windows is not installed then the key should not be found.  In this user's case it will be found, and they need to go trash it.  One does that either via regedit and navigate to the key or from a fully-elevated (eg right click -> Run as Administrator) cmd prompt:

64-bit:  reg delete "hklm\software\wow6432node\ibm\client access\currentversion" /f 
32-bit:  reg delete "hklm\software\ibm\client access\currentversion" /f